# How to read a datafile that has an integer value preceding the acutal JSON dictionary portion of the record?

Tags: python

The file has many records; here are 2 records to show the format:

```
3830591998918656: {"id":"2208ef95-355c-53a6-96bc-206a4831f2fe","data":"Tu pidneg."}
548113328635904: {"id":"d5887987-bf5d-5813-b524-722ffff11882","data":"Vubitaira lifo."}
```

I want to read the file and display records from this file; however the integer numbers at the beginning of the record is not allowing be to read in the datafile.
If I was to edit the datafile and remove e.g. the integer: `3830591998918656`, then I am able to execute python code to read the records and display them. Also if I was to move that integer into the dictionary as an attribute then I could read and display the file.
e.g. input updated as such:

```
{"score":3830591998918656,"id":"2208ef95-355c-53a6-96bc-206a4831f2fe","data":"Tu pidneg."}
{"score":548113328635904,"id":"d5887987-bf5d-5813-b524-722ffff11882","data":"Vubitaira lifo."}
```

I run the code:

```
import json
import os
readinputfile = []
print("Started Reading JSON file which contains multiple JSON document")
with open('2rec_example_input_data_1.data') as f:
    for jsonObj in f:
        readinputfileDict = json.loads(jsonObj)
        readinputfile.append(readinputfileDict)
print("Printing each JSON Decoded Object")
for inputrec in readinputfile:
    print(inputrec["score"], inputrec["id"], inputrec["data"])
```

Then I can get a display of:

```
3830591998918656 2208ef95-355c-53a6-96bc-206a4831f2fe Tu pidneg.
548113328635904 d5887987-bf5d-5813-b524-722ffff11882 Vubitaira lifo.
```

How does one write code in Python to read the file and display the records without having to change the structure of the file by taking that first integer and moving it into the Json dictionary portion of the file and naming it e.g. score.

Can it be done or does one need to fix the file as it is not acceptable in the format it is in?

Comment: Is each record on a separate line? Or do some records span multiple lines?

Comment: each record is on a single line; however each record is of various length as the last attribute "data" has various length of text.  Someone suggested below to split each line of the input file into the two pieces and add the first piece to the JSON in the second one. So I will try that and see how it works also.

Answer (score 1):

No need to modify the file, even in Python. Just split the line first before parsing the JSON string.

```
with open('2rec_example_input_data_1.data') as f:
    for line in f:
        number, jsonStr= line.split(' ', 1)
        json_obj = json.loads(jsonStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to split each line of the input file into the two pieces and then create the dictionaries you want from the two pieces.

```
import json
import re

readinputfile = []
with open('2rec_example_input_data_1.data') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = re.match(r'(\d+):\s(.+)', line)
        if match:
            readinputfileDict = {'score': match.group(1)}  # Initialize.
            readinputfileDict.update(json.loads(match.group(2))) # Copy the rest.
            readinputfile.append(readinputfileDict)

for inputrec in readinputfile:
    print(inputrec)
```

Output displayed:

```
{'score': '3830591998918656', 'id': '2208ef95-355c-53a6-96bc-206a4831f2fe', 'data': 'Tu pidneg.'}
{'score': '548113328635904', 'id': 'd5887987-bf5d-5813-b524-722ffff11882', 'data': 'Vubitaira lifo.'}
```

Comment: OK; Thank you..this is starting to work.  I made some slight changes as follows as I want to have the output be all displayed in Json format; new code added below in code above; and input file looks like as shown below.

Comment: 3830591998918656: {"id":"2208ef95-355c-53a6-96bc-206a4831f2fe","data":"Tu pidneg."}
548113328635904: {"id":"d5887987-bf5d-5813-b524-722ffff11882","data":"Vubitaira sero."}

Comment: When I run it now it displays output as:  {'id': '2208ef95-355c-53a6-96bc-206a4831f2fe', 'data': 'Tu pidneg.', 'score': '3830591998918656'}
{'id': 'd5887987-bf5d-5813-b524-722ffff11882', 'data': 'Vubitaira sero.', 'score': '548113328635904'}

Comment: so now I have the output in json for all the 3 tuples; id, data and score. However I need score in the 1st tuple position; ; moving/changing (1) or (2) for the readinputfile is for input so output has to be manipulated somehow; maybe a write command on the inputrec can be done to get the correct order and then I can print the inputrec to show it is in the correct order.  Is this the best way to manipulate the position of each of these fields for the order I want? Thanks in advance..

Comment: if the current output e.g. is displaying:                                                            {'score': '3830591998918656', 'id': '2208ef95-355c-53a6-96bc-206a4831f2fe', 'data': 'Tu pidneg.'}   How can the 'data' attribute be dropped from the Json? Does a subscript have to be used to just add the 'id' attribute? Trying to display the record as: {'score': '3830591998918656', 'id': '2208ef95-355c-53a6-96bc-206a4831f2fe'}.  Any feedback would be appreciated..thanks in advance.

Comment: `{'score': '3830591998918656', 'id': '2208ef95-355c-53a6-96bc-206a4831f2fe', 'data': 'Tu pidneg.'}` is a dictionary. You can remove items from a dictionary with e.g. `del readinputfileDict['data']`. I don't understand the part of your question about added the 'id' attribute.